# WordPress Gravity Form Field Validation

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I have a WordPress sites using Gravity Forms, and within this form I have a field that requires a special 10 digit code to be input by the user that matches up with a database of codes (there are 20 of these codes). If the code that has been input matches one of the 20 codes, then they can proceed with submitting the form. If it doesn’t match then they cannot proceed.

Please advise on how to create a PHP function that achieves this?

Many thanks

Comment: What did you try so far? Did you write any code already? Are you familiar with both PHP and writing WordPress plugins? Showing that you did research and put effort in your question will increase the probability that users will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a snippet that you might find helpful.

http://gravitywiz.com/require-existing-value-submission-gravity-forms/

To use this snippet for your needs, you would need to setup a new form that will be used to store the 20 codes. Add a field a Single Line Text field to your form. Add an entry for each code.

On your original form, you can now configure the snippet to check the values of the new form for a valid code. Happy to answer any questions.

```
new GW_Value_Exists_Validation( array(
    'target_form_id'  => 613, // your original form ID where the codes will be validated
    'target_field_id' => 1,   // the field on your original form where the user should enter the code
    'source_form_id'  => 519, // the new form you will create to store your codes
    'source_field_id' => 1,   // the field on the new form that will store one code per submission
    'validation_message' => 'Hey! This isn\'t a valid reference number.' // the error message displayed if the user does not enter a valid code
) );
```